# How to convert long to int in .net?

Tags: c#, casting

I am developing window phone 7 application in silverlight. I am new to the window phone 7 application. I have the long value in String format as follows

```
String Am = AmountTextBox.Text.ToString()
```

The AmountTextBox.Text.ToString() in the above code is long value which is in string format. I want to store a 15 digit inter value in my application.

I found the following link for conversion.

[Can I convert long to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858904/can-i-convert-long-to-int)

How should I convert a long value which is in string format to int ? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ? If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me.

Comment: An `Int32` does only have 10 digits (`2,147,483,647`, unsigned `4,294,967,295`), where do you want to store the other 5?

Comment: I am using XML as a database in my application. I am using <Amount></Amount> node for storing the entire 15 digit value. Then should I covert my String value into the long ? Please guide me. I am new to this type of conversions

Comment: So, I'm going to guess that you really want to convert a `String` that contains a number into a `long`?

Comment: yes I really want to convert string to long

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't store a 15 digit integer since the maximum value for an integer is 2,147,483,647.

What's wrong with a `long`-Value?

You could use [TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zc2x2b1h%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to get the `long`-Value from yout user input:

```
String Am = AmountTextBox.Text.ToString();
long l;
Int64.TryParse(Am, out l);
```

It will return `false` if the text can't be converted to `long`, so it's pretty safe to use.

Otherwise, converting a `long` to `int` is a easy as

```
int i = (int)yourLongValue;
```

if you're happy with discarding MSBs and taking LSBs.

Answer (score 48):

Use [Convert.ToInt32()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/813w40de.aspx). If the value is too big for an int then it will throw an OverflowException.

This method can take a whole range of values, including Int64 and Strings.

Answer (score 2):

You have a number stored as a `string`, and you want to convert it to a numeric type.

You can't convert it to type `int` (also known as `Int32`), because as the other answers have mentioned, that type does not have sufficient range to store your intended value.

Instead, you need to convert the value to a `long` (also known as `Int64`), instead. The simplest and most painless way to do that is using the [`TryParse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xssxkb0k.aspx), which converts a string representation of a number to its 64-bit signed integer equivalent.

The advantage of using this method (instead of something like `Parse`) is that it does not throw an exception if the conversion fails. Since exceptions are expensive, you should avoid throwing them unless absolutely necessary. Instead, you specify the string containing the number to convert as the first argument to the method, and an `out` value to receive the converted number if the conversion succeeds. The return value is a Boolean, indicating whether or not the conversion was successful.

Sample code:

```
private void ConvertNumber(string value)
{
    Int64 number; // receives the converted numeric value, if conversion succeeds

    bool result = Int64.TryParse(value, out number);
    if (result)
    {
         // The return value was True, so the conversion was successful
         Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
    }
    else
    {
        // Make sure the string object is not null, for display purposes
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = String.Empty;
        }

         // The return value was False, so the conversion failed
        Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.", value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The maximum `Int32` value in C# is 2,147,483,647, shorter than the 15 digits you require.

Are you sure you need to convert this value to an int? It sounds like you'd be better off storing the value in a `long`, or leaving it as a `String`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I think I should convert my string value into long. How to do this ? Can you please provide me any code.

Answer (score 1):

A Long value stores more data than an Integer 32 value, so if you want to keep all 15 digits you can't convert to a standard Integer.

But aside from 'which' datatype you want to use, the Convert class should help you i.e. Convert.ToInt64 which may do what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the input `long` to `Object` and then convert it to `int32`.

```
Object a = e;
int w = Convert.ToInt32(a);
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

In C# `int` has 32 bits and `long` has 64 bits. Therefore not all values of `long` can be `int`. Maybe get an array of `int`s?

```
public static int[] ToIntArray(long l)
{
    var longBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(l);

    // Get integers from the first and the last 4 bytes of long
    return new int[] {
        BitConverter.ToInt32(longBytes, 0),
        BitConverter.ToInt32(longBytes, 4)
    };
}
```

Comment: I believe it can in practice though, for example a huge number of seconds, divided by seconds in a decade - it suddenly cannot meaningfully exceed int32, but the original value can.