# Cannot convert long to int Issue in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, int64

In the below code i want to add 0 before the number (ie) if the number is 96333 it should be 096333 when i execute it  i am facing issue cannot convert long to int.Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
  public FileDto GenerateBarcodeImage(Int64 BarCodeNumber)
    {
        //string s = BarCodeNumber.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
        string result = BarCodeNumber.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
        int sds = Int64.Parse(result);
        return GetBarcodeImage(sds);
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception being thrown?

Comment: `Int64.Parse("096333")` will return you `96333 `, You will lose all zero's on left so whats the use of converting

Comment: By parsing back to Int64, you lose all zeroes to the left. Those are just formatting, not representative of your actual integer value.

Comment: I don't know what GetCodeBarImage is suppose to do but it looks wrong working with a int instead of a string if you want to display those zeros

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert long to int in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192862/how-to-convert-long-to-int-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
int sds = Int64.Parse(result);
```

with

```
long sds = Int64.Parse(result);
```

Comment: Or `int sds = Int32.Parse(result)`

Answer (score 2):

`long` is more precise than `int`. An implicit cast can be done only from lower to bigger precision, because there is no risk of loosing information (because the smallest and biggest values of `int` can be easily contained in a `long`).

If your value may be bigger than the capacity of `int`, change the type of sds to Int64. I suppose your function `GetBarcodeImage` takes an `Int64` as parameter, if not you may want to change that too.

If your value can be contained in an `integer`, juste change your `GenerateBarcodeImage` function to take and `int` as parameter.

Think carefully to the consequences of casting a number to a lower precision. Read the [story of the first Ariane 5 launch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(spacecraft)#Launch_failure) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int sds = Int32.Parse(result);
```

instead of

```
int sds = Int64.Parse(result);
```

As correctly pointed by Mr47 when you are parsing back the number to Int64, you will lose all zeroes to the left.