# C# Recover Int64 from negative Int32

Tags: c#, parsing, integer, recover

I want to recover this `long` value, that was mistakenly converted to `int`

```
long longValue = 11816271602;
int intValue = (int)longValue; // gives -1068630286
long ActualLong = ?
```

Right shift `32` bits of (`intValue >> 32`) gives *incorrect* result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858904/can-i-convert-long-to-int

Comment: Is there any possible way to recover?

Answer (score 5):

Well, the initial value

```
long longValue = 11816271602L; // 0x02C04DFEF2
```

is *five* bytes long. When you cast the value to `Int32` which is *four* bytes long

```
int intValue = (int)longValue; // 0xC04DFEF2 (note 1st byte 02 absence)
```

you inevitably *lose* the 1st byte and *can't* restore it back.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible. If you take a look at the binary representation you can see the reason:

```
10 1100 0000 0100 1101 1111 1110 1111 0010
```

As you can see, this number has 34-bit and not only 32-bit.